# How can i change my current code to set my div to a min-height instead of a height jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone help me to set my div to `min-height` instead of a normal height. Cause when I press Learn more button it will go over my `div` cause the function is made for setting a height instead of equal height.

```
$.fn.equalHeight = function() {
var maxHeight = 0;
return this.each(function(index, box) {
    var boxHeight = $(box).height();
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, boxHeight);
}).height(maxHeight);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/5505/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following URL where your issue has been fixed.

CSS

```
.equalheightz{
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;

}
.phide{
  display:none;
}
h3{
  font-size:25px;
  color:#333;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
p{
  color:#333;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

JS :

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.blok1show').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().find('.phide').slideToggle('fast');

   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/5506/

Comment: There is 1 more problem with this. the blocks are not equal height anymore. for when i have different intro texts

Comment: the height of the each block is depends on your intro text, if you wish to set default height to the text, then it will overlap with other blocks, try to keep equal length of all intro text or try some fixed height for the intro text.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CSS property by using:

```
$(".foo").css("min-height", function(){ 
    return $(this).height();
});
```

You can save that to a variable or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(#YOUR-DiV).style.minHeight = "100px";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_minheight.asp